# ClassNotFoundException while using apache commons net

Tags: java, maven, classnotfoundexception, apache-commons-net

Getting the following while using Apache's commons-net library.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.net.SocketFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

This class is loaded transitively by another one.

The environment is maven and commons-net  has been loaded via the pom file.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
  <classifier>ftp</classifier>
  <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

There is no SSL connection. Do I need to specify using java.security ?

Comment: Is the classifier ``ftp`` really necessary?

Comment: no. but removing it does not make any difference.

Comment: So your Maven build (or Gradle build) works just fine without errors? Is the stated dependency in the dependency tree (hierarchy)?

Comment: maven build (actually test) does not work with or without the classifier. here's the dependency tree.

Comment: [INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.dbunit:dbunit:jar:2.4.9:test
[INFO] |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:test
[INFO] +- oracle:ojdbc16:jar:11.2.0.3:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.2:test
[INFO] +- jp.ossc:nimbus:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] \- commons-net:commons-net:jar:2.0:compile

Comment: First question: if the maven build does not work, your error message you get is showing after executing what?; second question: do you have the "commons-net-2.0.jar" file (or "commons-net-2.0-ftp.jar") inside your build result?

Comment: Maven compile works. The test does not work.

Comment: This commons-net is a transitive dependency.